# Kitchen Cabinet with Face Frame, Full Overlay Door Hinges

Tags: cabinetry, hinges

I'm interested in learning how to build shaker kitchen cabinets. I want them to look like the picture below. I want them to have a standard `1 1/2" face frame` and `full overlay` cabinet doors and drawers.

My question is about the door hinges required. In doing my research, I can only find `1/2" overlay` or `1 1/4" overlay` European concealed door hinges:

- Wouldn't I need `1 1/2" overlay` door hinges in order to make the end of the door flush with the end of the cabinet, like in the picture below?
- Wouldn't the `1 1/4" overlay` hinges leave `1/4"` of space between the door and the end of the cabinet?

[image: Cabinet door overlay]

Comment: Wait, you want to make new face frame cabinets that look like Euro-style cabinets?  Why are you doing this?  Euro cabinets are much easier to make and give you a lot more room in your drawers and make your cabinet interiors much more accessible.  They also open up possibilities like full-width drawers inside base cabinets.

Comment: @SaSSafraS1232 Yes I think I finally started realizing that - I have actually been researching and drawing up plans for frameless cabinets as we speak, lol. I just read somewhere that framed cabinets were a lot stronger. Thanks!

Comment: While I was redoing my kitchen, a friend told me about [Plan N Design](https://www.planndesign.com) It has lots of design ideas for the kitchen and the whole home. Hope it helps!